# Stable/unstable equilibrium points of autonomous system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is the equilibrium point $0$ of $y'(t)=y(t)\sin(t)$ stable or asymptotically stable?

Comment: You can solve this via separation. What is the relation from $y(0)$ to $y(2\pi)$?

Comment: Since it's a separable equation, we can solve it and the solution is c*exp(-cos(t)) for some constant c. But how to know if the equilibrium point is stable?

Comment: What is your definition of stability? What is the maximal value a solution can reach if $y(0)$ is the basis value?